# Why Task scheduler withoutOverlapping method not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: scheduled-tasks, laravel-5

I have tried withoutOverlapping method in Laravel 5.2 But it is not working for me. Can anybody help me in figuring out my issue

```
$schedule->call(function(){
           $newUserStrava = new StravaController();
           $newUserStrava->getNewTrackerActivity();
       })->everyMinute()->name('testoverlap')->withoutOverlapping();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because it create a mutex file  when there is fatal error while running the schedule job and it does not re-initiate the schedule job again. You can refer to below link for the solution.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-task-scheduler-after-fatal-error-when-withoutoverlapping-is-set